# Django python trying to use forms with token does not work for me

Tags: python, django, forms, token

I'm learning django, in this moment I'm trying to implement web forms, actually some of them  works fine with the data base model but I'm trying to make a new one without use the models. The problem is that django show me the token and not the value typed in the form.

I hope you can help me, to understand more about it.

URLS:

```
url(r'^test', views.test),
```

VIEWS:

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        return HttpResponse(request.POST)       



    return render(request, 'datos.html')
```

DATOS HTML:

```
<form action="/test" method="post" name="myForm"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I run this django show me:

**csrfmiddlewaretoken**

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

To protect from [Cross-Site_Request_Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attack, for each post request we need to send a csrf token, from the form, which is missing in your form, you can get rid of this error by modifying your form as follows.

```
<form action="/test" method="POST" name="myForm"> 
     {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and You need to get the data from your views,

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Getting the value of text field from the form
        # If the value is empty set the default value to None
        text = request.POST.get('text', None)

        # Do not return the POST request
        # Return the value you get from the form
        return HttpResponse(text)       


       # This code is not going to execute 
       # Return is already encountered above in our code 
        return render(request, 'datos.html')
       # To send data to form do, 
       # return render(request, 'datos.html', {'my_data': text})
```